# Use html to replicate spreadsheet sum formulas to create an agenda

Tags: html, sum, formula, spreadsheet, replicate

I have created an agenda in a spreadsheet. I am moving this to a webpage where i use html. I can create a table and list every cell, but I would like to replicate the spreadsheet formulas so that if I change the duration of one lesson, the rest of the agenda auto-updates. The image I have attached illustrates this in excel.

[image]

Comment: look at google charts https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

Answer (score 0):

Save your spreadsheet to OneDrive using a free Microsoft account. On OneDrive you can get embed code for the spreadsheet and embed it into your web site. Make changes to the spreadsheet in Excel Online or desktop Excel or on your mobile device.